# Outline a PNG image

Tags: code-golf, graphical-output

## Intro (semi fictional)

I'm the solo developer of a game, I'm already struggling with character design as is. Hence I've thought of a smart solution, I'll just use images for regular monsters, outline them a bit and suddenly they are boss monsters! That will save me from thinking up new bosses yay.
However, I have approximately 100 monster designs already and I wouldn't like duplicating them all and manually drawing an outline to the images...

## Challenge

Given a file name (of a [PNG](https://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/) file) as input, you should write a program/function which will draw an outline around every non-transparent pixel. The program/function should save the output file to a new file called `a.png`

## What does outlining mean

Outlining is the process of adding non-transparent pixels in the place of transparent pixels, around pixels which were non-transparent already. Any transparent pixel has an opacity of exactly 0%, anything else is defined as non-transparent. Any pixel which will be outlined will have an opacity of 100%, aka the alpha channel of that pixel will be 255.

## Input

Your program/function should take 3 variables as input. Feel free to provide these as function parameters, read them from stdin or any other method which suits you best.

The first variable is the **file name**, which is always a PNG file.
The second variable is the **outline colour**, which is a round integer, you can also take the colour from 3 separate `r,g,b` byte values.
The third variable is the **outline width**, also an integer.

## Outline width

The width of the outline equals the maximum distance any transparent pixel should have to a non-transparent pixel in order to be outlined. The distance is calculated using the [Manhattan distance](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Manhattan_distance) between two points.
If the input image has only 1 non-transparent pixel, at `[0,0]` and the outline width is 2, then the following pixels will be coloured:
`[0,1] [0,-1] [1,0] [-1,0] [1,1] [-1,-1] [1,-1] [-1,1] [2,0] [-2,0] [0,2] [0,-2]`, for these have a manhattan distance of 2 or less from the coloured pixel

## Test cases

The following test cases are scaled up 7 times for visibility, so every block of 7 pixels should be treated as a single pixel

These are the input images used for the test cases:

```
input1.png
```

[image: testcase1_before]

```
input2.png
```

[image]

```
input3.png
```

[image]

These are the actual test cases:

```
input1.png, 0xFF0000, 0
```

[image]

```
input1.png, 0xFF0000, 1
```

[image]

```
input1.png, 0xFF0000, 2
```

[image]

```
input1.png, 0xFF0000, 3
```

[image]

```
input1.png, 0xFF0000, 10
```

[image]

```
input2.png, 0xFF0000, 2
```

[image]

```
input3.png, 0x000000, 2
```

[image]

Click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODCbA.jpg) for the full Imgur album.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), [standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) apply! Feel free to submit your own images as test cases, since these pixel images aren't very creative ;)

Comment: Could the color also be taken as three separate `r,g,b` values?

Comment: @flawr also fine with me

Comment: I assume you enlarged the images in the challenge description. Can you also post the ones with the original size?

Comment: The PNG image requirement ruins the challenge.

Answer (score 4):

## Matlab, 202 bytes

```
function f(i,r,g,b,n);[i,~,a]=imread(i);[x,y]=ndgrid(abs(-n:n));d=permute([r,g,b,255]',3:-1:1);I=cat(3,i,a);J=uint8(bsxfun(@times,~~convn(a,x+y<=n,'s')&~a,d))+I;imwrite(J(:,:,1:3),'a.png','Al',J(:,:,4))
```

As always:

> Convolution is the key to success.

The function can be called like so:

```
f('my_image.png', red_int, green_int, blue_int, dist)
```

Commented:

```
function f(i,r,g,b,n)
[i,~,a]=imread(i);                   %read image and alpha channel
[x,y]=ndgrid(abs(-n:n));             %computations for convolution kernel
d=permute([r,g,b,255]',3:-1:1);      %create 'pixel' that will be inserted
I=cat(3,i,a);                        %concatenate image and alpha channel
J=uint8(bsxfun(@times,~~convn(a,x+y<=n,'s')&~a,d))+I; %find border via convolution of kernel, insert pixels and recombine with original
imwrite(J(:,:,1:3),'a.png','Al',J(:,:,4)) %write file
```

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 559 chars

### Ungolfed

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
$p=$argv[1];
$img = ImageCreateFromPng($p);
$width = imagesx($img);
$height = imagesy($img);
$new = ImageCreateFromPng($p);
alphaFix($img);
alphaFix($new);
$inv = '2130706432';
for($w=0;$w<$width;$w++)
    for($h=0;$h<$height;$h++)
    {
        $color = ImageColorAt($img, $w, $h);
        if($color != $inv)
            for($x=0;$x<$width;$x++)
                for($y=0;$y<$height;$y++)
                {
                    if(abs($h - $y) + abs($w - $x) <= intval($argv[3]))
                    {
                        $_color = ImageColorAt($img, $x, $y);
                        if($_color == $inv)
                            imagesetpixel($new, $x, $y, hexdec($argv[2]));
                    }
                }
    }
imagepng($new, str_replace(".png", ".border.png", $p));

function alphaFix(&$img)
{
    $background = imagecolorallocate($img, 0, 0, 0);
    imagecolortransparent($img, $background);
    imagealphablending($img, false);
    imagesavealpha($img, true);
}
?>
```

### Golfed

```
<?error_reporting(0);$j=$argv[1];$g=ImageCreateFromPng($j);$e=imagesx($g);$b=imagesy($g);$l=ImageCreateFromPng($j);a($g);a($l);$f='2130706432';for($m=0;$m<$e;$m++)for($l=0;$l<$b;$l++){$d=ImageColorAt($g,$m,$l);if($d!=$f)for($k=0;$k<$e;$k++)for($i=0;$i<$b;$i++){if(abs($l-$i)+abs($m-$k)<=intval($argv[3])){$c=ImageColorAt($g,$k,$i);if($c==$f)imagesetpixel($l,$k,$i,hexdec($argv[2]));}}}imagepng($l,str_replace(".png",".border.png",$j));function a(&$g){$a=imagecolorallocate($g,0,0,0);imagecolortransparent($g,$a);imagealphablending($g,0);imagesavealpha($g,1);}
```

### Syntax

```
php outline.php "image1.png" 0xFF0000 1
                     |           |    |
                     |           |    *- Border Size
                     |           *------ Color HEX
                     *------------------ Image Name
```

### Examples

I made an [Imgur album](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJ9nH.jpg), because I slightly changed the images and there you can also see the arguments I passed my script.