# Count my Pluses

Tags: code-golf, string, grid, matrix, binary-matrix

Your task is, to count how many pluses I have.

### What Pluses?

- The no plus: 0 Points

```
-
```

- The naïve Plus: 1 Point

```
+
```

- The double Plus: 2 Points

```
 +
+++
 +
```

- The mega double plus: 3 Points

```
    +
   +++
    +
 +  +  +
+++++++++
 +  +  +
    +
   +++
    +
```

Pluses of higher order than 3 must be ignored.

### Rules

- Input will only consist of two characters - and +, and it will always be rectangular.
- Input can be a string, an array or a binary matrix (then + is 1 and - is 0).
- Output must be the sum of all detected pluses (trailing newline/ whitespace allowed).
- Pluses can overlap (see Examples below)
- [Default I/O rules apply](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods)
- [Default Loop holes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) apply

### Examples

```
-+-
+-+
+--
```

Out: 4

```
-+-
+++
+++
```

Out: 9 (7 naïve pluses and 1 double plus)

```
++++++
++++++
++++++
++++++
```

Out: 40 (24 naïve pluses and 8 double pluses)

```
----+-----
+--+++----
----++----
-+--+--++-
+++++++++-
-+--+--++-
----+-+---
---+++----
+---++++++
```

Out: 49 (36 naïve pluses, 5 double pluses and 1 mega double plus)

```
++++++++++
++++++++++
++++++++++
++++++++++
++++++++++
++++++++++
++++++++++
++++++++++
++++++++++
```

Out: 208 (90 naïve pluses, 56 double pluses and 2 mega double plus)

Comment: [sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/23591/96037)

Comment: Could you add a test case where one or more intersections of a "mega double plus" overlap, thereby invalidating it?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what Shaggy means, but I would suggest a test case with the same dimensions as the last one but with all pluses--my current Jelly solution is *incredibly* wrong for that input

Comment: @Shaggy and Unrelated String I'll do it tommorow, but I don't know too what Shaggy meant

Comment: I think he means that there are spaces in the `mega double plus`, but if you drew two of them overlapped slightly it would invalidate both of them because you'd get a plus in one of the spaces

Comment: @simonalexander2005 Thanks, I'll add both test cases

Comment: @simonalexander2005 If you mean something like [this](https://imgur.com/bGpDkxt), then I think it is still valid, space doesn't mean -. I am adding just the second testcase suggested by Unrelated String for now.

Comment: @Arnauld thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Kaddath That's true. The double plus itself is worth 2 points, the naives 5. So if the double plus is a test case, the output should be 7.

Comment: @math you're right seems like the examples numbers didn't reach my brain when i read them, deleting my comment

Answer (score 16):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>29</s> <s>28</s> 24  bytes

```
z2Y6ttX*,GbZ+5Mz=z]yytvs
```

Input is a binary matrix with `1` for `'+'` and `0` for `'-'`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/v8oo0qykJEJLxz0pStvUt8q2KraysqSs@P//aAMFQwUDayBWMASTBrEA) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##y00syfmf8L/KKNKspCRCS8c9KUrb1LfKtiq2srKkrPi/S1RFyP9oAwVDBQNrIFYwBJMGsVxwMUOwGBACxcC0ApIYfjbYFAg0VICxIPYYQNXAxBDqkMUMkfQaItyDArGrQ7bXEMUOVHsNFZBFIa4GAA).

#### Explanation

> [Convolution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/79313/36398) [is](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/192680/write-a-function-that-returns-an-iterable-object-of-all-valid-points-4-direction/192694#comment459298_192694) [the](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/79453/36398) [key](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89194/36398) [to](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200078/36398) [success](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/92254/36398)

```
z       % Implicit input. Number of nonzeros. This is the number of naive pluses
2Y6     % Push [0 1 0; 1 1 1; 0 1 0] (predefined literal): pattern of double plus
ttX*    % Duplicate twice. Kronecker product: pattern of mega-double plus
,       % Do twice
  G     %   Push input again
  b     %   Bubble up third-topmost entry in the stack. This moves either the
        %   double of mega-double pattern to top
  Z+    %   2D convolution, maintaining size
  5M    %   Push the last input to the last function again: the pattern
  z     %   Number of nonzeros. This gives 5 or 25 for double or mega-double
  =     %   Equal? Element-wise. This detects if the result of the convolution
        %   equals the number of ones in the pattern, which implies that the
        %   pattern has been found
  z     %   Number of nonzeros. This is how many times the pattern has been found  
]       % End
yyt     % Duplicate the top two elements, then the top element. This effectively
        % gives weight 2 and 3 to double and mega-double pluses
vs      % Concatenate all stack contents. Sum. Implicit display
```

Answer (score 9):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>146 ... 140</s>  137 bytes

Expects a binary matrix.

```javascript
m=>m.map((r,y)=>r.map((c,x)=>t+=c+=(g=(X,k=6)=>k>>8||(m[y+Y+k%5%3]||0)[x-X+k%27%4]&g(X,k+46))(Y=0)&&2+3*g(Y=3)*g(-3)*g``*g(0,Y=6)),t=0)|t
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rU/LTsMwELznK6xKTbxsbEVtKUjIucEP9NKqjdTITULIqzgGtSJ8e7CTIoq4stLuzoxn1/ZL/B63UuVHzermkPSp6CsRVryKj5Qq/wwiVCOR/skQjUKioJmga78QS6MUYXjfdbTannGDxfR2Oo@6LoDtia0Nnd1NF5GbWTculgB0IwJw3RnObzKD52Aas3W/NyjwN2Yn@NqYOt2r5PUtVwn10tYDrpL48JSXyepcSxoA181Kq7zOKPD2WOaaTnb1rp4ATxv1GMtn2hIRkg@HkIoI0v6YjMX@SNnjLedcRQOXlqNtgnjoAcCDmZVN3TZlwssmoymtrPgJPUPmIEOTzHEGgjikLRf8tznMBNpip5mRBjioF4iDAceNY/xSxw14GfvegCO@esDVtf8OvwA)

### How?

#### Helper function

The helper function \$g\$ tests whether there's a 'Double Plus' inside the \$3\times3\$ submatrix whose top-left corner is located at position \$(x-X,y+Y)\$.

We start with \$k=6\$ and add \$46\$ to \$k\$ after each iteration. The relative coordinates in the submatrix are given by:

$$\begin{align}&dx=(k\bmod 27)\bmod 4\\
&dy=(k\bmod 5)\bmod 3\end{align}$$

```
  k | k%27 | dx=k%27%4 | k%5 | dy=k%5%3 | (dx, dy)          | 0 1 2
----+------+-----------+-----+----------+--------------  ---+-------
  6 |   6  |     2     |  1  |     1    | (+2, +1) (A)    0 | - C -
 52 |  25  |     1     |  2  |     2    | (+1, +2) (B)    1 | E D A
 98 |  17  |     1     |  3  |     0    | (+1, +0) (C)    2 | - B -
144 |   9  |     1     |  4  |     1    | (+1, +1) (D)
190 |   1  |     1     |  0  |     0    | (+1, +0) (C)
236 |  20  |     0     |  1  |     1    | (+0, +1) (E)
```

The cell at \$(+1, +0)\$ is tested twice, which is not an issue.

The next value of \$k\$ is \$282\$ which triggers the test `k >> 8` and stops the recursion.

```javascript
g = (X, k = 6) =>    // g is a recursive function taking X and a counter k
  k >> 8 || (        //   if k = 282, stop the recursion and return 1
    ( m[ y + Y +     //   otherwise, test the cell located at
         k % 5 % 3 ] //   row y + Y + ((k mod 5) mod 3)
      || 0           //
    )[ x - X +       //   and column x - X + ((k mod 27) mod 4)
       k % 27 % 4 ]  //
  )                  //
  & g(X, k + 46)     //   do a recursive call with k + 46
```

#### Main function

**NB**: Among many different possible choices, the initial value of \$k\$ in \$g\$ was forced to \$6\$ so that it allows us to do `g(0, Y = 6)` in the main function without breaking anything.

```javascript
m =>                 // m[] = input matrix
m.map((r, y) =>      // for each row r[] at position y in m[]:
  r.map((c, x) =>    //   for each cell c at position x in r[]:
    t +=             //     add to t:
    c +=             //       1 point if c = 1
      g(Y = 0) && 2  //       2 points if there's a Double Plus at (x, y)
      + 3 *          //       3 points if there are also Double Pluses at:
      g(Y = 3) *     //         (x - 3, y + 3)
      g(-3) *        //         (x + 3, y + 3)
      g`` *          //         (x, y + 3)
      g(0, Y = 6)    //         (x, y + 6)
  ),                 //   end of inner map()
  t = 0              //   start with t = 0
) | t                // end of outer map(); return t
```

Comment: Output for the last test case seems to be off by three. Yours outputs 208 while the actual result is 205

Comment: @RecursiveCo. The correct answer is 208. (Now fixed by the OP.)

Comment: ES6, 138 bytes: `m=>m.map((r,y)=>r.map((c,x)=>t+=c+=(g=X=>k=k>8||(325>>k|(m[y+Y+k/3|0]||0)[x-X+k++%3])&g(X))(Y=0)&&2+3*g(Y=3)*g(-3)*g``*g(!(Y=6))),k=t=0)|t`; ES2020, 135 bytes: `m=>m.map((r,y)=>r.map((c,x)=>t+=c+=(g=X=>k=k>8||(325>>k|m[y+Y+k/3|0]?.[x-X+k++%3])&g(X))(Y=0)&&2+3*g(Y=3)*g(-3)*g``*g(!(Y=6))),k=t=0)|t`

Comment: 137: `m=>m.map((r,y)=>r.map((c,x)=>t+=c+=(g=X=>k=k>8||(325>>k|(m[y+Y+k/3|0]||0)[x-X+k++%3])&g(X))(Y=0)&&2+3*g(Y=3)*g(-3)*g``*g(0,Y=6)),k=t=0)|t`

Comment: @tsh Nice optimization. I was trying to find a version of `g` that directly tests the relevant points rather than iterating over all of them. The result is also 137 bytes for now.

Comment: @Arnauld I’m trying to change g’s parameter to Y and add x directly without using X. But I’m on <s>rails</s> my mobile and is a bit slow.

Comment: @tsh Just to make sure I got it right: your version takes advantage of the fact that `k` can be safely re-initialized to either 0 or 1, correct?

Comment: @Arnauld Yes, and we don’t quite care if it initialized to 0 or 1, as 0 is ignored so far. I also tried to reuse k in the product: `t+=c+(…)(…)*2+k*g(…)*…*3`. But it doesn’t save a byte.

Comment: 136: `m=>m.map((r,y)=>r.map((c,x)=>t+=c+=(g=Y=>k=k>8||(325>>k|(m[y-Y+k%3]||0)[x+k++/3|0])&g(Y))\`\`&&2+3*g(3,x+=3)*g(-3)*g\`\`*g(0,x+=3)),k=t=0)|t`

Answer (score 8):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 33 bytes

```
×3\€ḊṖ
ZÇZaÇḤ
ÇJ%3ZƙƲ⁺€Ç€€a3,,ÇFS
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///wdOOYR01rHu7oerhzGlfU4faoxMPtD3cs4Trc7qVqHHVs5rFNjxp3AVUcbgcSQJRorKNzuN0t@P/RyQ93Ln7UMOfQtrpD2x41zH24ewtQ2hbI0garjfz/X1dbl0tbVxuIdbnquMA8bW0wrgORUA4mBVQLBNogAmSALlAMzASLQpnaYAXaEDMhAEUUYoI2VBvMBG0IG9kJSBZTnQkA)

:/

I want to say this is very golfable, but the entire approach is probably not the ideal one. Now agrees with Luis Mendo's MATL solution on a test case I made up, and at the cost of only one byte so that's cool I guess

```
×3\€ḊṖ    Helper link 1: detect centers of +++
   €      For each row,
 3\       reduce over overlapping windows of length 3:
×         multiply.
    ḊṖ    Remove the first and last rows.

ZÇZaÇḤ    Helper link 2: detect double plus centers
   aÇ     Keep the horizontal (centers of) +++es which align with
ZÇZ       the vertical (centers of) +++es,
     Ḥ    and double.

ÇJ%3ZƙƲ⁺€Ç€€a3,,ÇFS    Main link: sum each tier of plus
Ç                      Get the matrix of double plus centers.
     ƙƲ                Group rows by
 J%3                   their indices mod 3
    Z                  and transpose each group;
       ⁺€              do it again to each group.
          €€           For each group in each group,
         Ç             detect the double plus pattern,
            a3         and replace the 16s with 3s.
              ,        Pair the result with the input,
               ,Ç      pair that pair with the double pluses,
                 FS    then flatten that all and return the sum.
```

Comment: nice, but I can't vote anymore.

Answer (score 8):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 141 bytes

```r
function(m)sum(m,a<-f(m,n<-nrow(m))*2,f(a,n,3)*3,na.rm=T)
f=function(m,n,k=1)sapply(n*k+seq(!m),function(i)all(i%%n>1,m[i+k*c(0,1,-1,n,-n)]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVDLCsIwELz3K/RQ2K1bSVQEofUrvImHUKyENlttFfXra7Ta2EcWZpbMzG5IWZ/iOr1xctUFg8HqZsCQisLUEkchl8XdXmOwoBQUMS0xWBKreWniHXpp7LJWzGKJlTqf8ydwkM2q4wWmBqn1aFR5Dtr3eSvJ7PUsCxIQJCmUNh0yHhDrExh1LfUDGuld4lOW0e5Hb8TRuCz2HJJWtB5GvuN67FaJnuZ6h5K8ye9I6pZoUbS9@EuObW3QzRxqnZchbexnvQA)

This can probably be improved by a lot.

The helper function `f` scans the matrix. For each cell, it counts 1 iff the cell and the cells at distance `k` in each of the 4 directions are all worth 1. For `k=1`, this corresponds to checking the 4 neighbours, and creates `a` which encodes the centres of the double pluses. We then run `f` on `a` with `k=3` to find the triple pluses. The entries near the edges end up as `NA`; they are ignored thanks to `na.rm=T`.

Answer (score 6):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup>80 69</sup> 60 bytes

```
[:+/@,[,2 3*((;[:,./^:2#"{~)#:2 7 2)4 :'y(x-:x&*);._3~$x'&><
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rU7BCsIwDL3nK@KUdTXrNjpBjU4EwZMnr0M9yEQ8KIjIRPDXZ7d1oKg3A2le0peXdyiGLY77uMIIN2WCE4gdJowCfdOzSRXgbLmYFylTOPVTX2Pc9bxRyn4Qrlm3nftDtlljH7XsIYublyvO3a4cBZv40cmFOxkXEran4zU7XyptEm5ifjVAtt2fsDfEBHfYMMzZCJQJKh8FphBVuJ5aSBXBdEBNvE1rBbJrjQLV2ARIez36vG4ZX4td@@a59gKv4j9YikonDUtHg18eXi7/H0oong)

<sup>-9 thanks to xash</sup>

Comment: Two small golfs for [-9](https://tio.run/##rU7BCsIwDL3nK@KUdTXrNjpBjU4EwZMnr0M9yEQ8KIjIRPDXZ7d1oKg3A2le0peXdyiGLY77uMIIN2WCE4gdJowCfdOzSRXgbLmYFylTOPVTX2Pc9bxRyn4Qrlm3nftDtlljH7XsIYublyvO3a4cBZv40cmFOxkXEran4zU7XyptEm5ifjVAtt2fsDfEBHfYMMzZCJQJKh8FphBVuJ5aSBXBdEBNvE1rBbJrjQLV2ARIez36vG4ZX4td@@a59gKv4j9YikonDUtHg18eXi7/H0oong)

Comment: btw. nice solution with the inline `4 :`

Comment: For showing previous scores, it makes more sense to use `<strike>num</strike>`

Comment: I don’t like how that looks as much even though i agree it’s semantically more accurate.

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), <s>150 149</s> 145 bytes

```python
lambda a:len(x("\+",a)+2*x((d:="\+(?="+(s:="\W"*~-a.find("\n"))+3*"\+"+s+"\+)..")[:-2],a)+3*x(d+f"(?={3*s+3*d+3*s+d})",a))
import re
x=re.findall
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU/BasQgED3Xr5A5aUZD2fTQBtx@Rg/ZHCwaKmRN0ByylPbXUzW7WwodGOeNb@Y9nS/Lx@Sb5zlsgzptoz6/G011O1rPVgYnBKE5HqqVMdOq1LNXBchixm9QfUtdD86bNOmBc2yqvIIRU@F1Dbxr5aHPEk2SMDhA2v9sqph6g7maL54tOHHneQoLDZasKtiiqsdxW2xcIlW0Ix0ASJQEJaaUqRP0qRfkl0DMWYiXG4ElyH9lV3i8S6TAfGQLmfgCy@0VYhnA3WqPP7e7Al7Xbgq447thflpPyDAF6oSlztPyx5Y8zMH5hQ3McQHqCCIjpSzffgA)

Input is a multiline string

Thanks to @Tipping Octopus for -1 byte
Thanks to @Neil for -4 bytes

### Ungolfed version

```python
import re
def f(a):
  s="\W"*(a.find("\n") - 1)
  d=f"\+(?={s}\+\+\+{s}\+).."

  return len(re.findall("\+", a) +
             2 * re.findall(d[:-2], a) +
             3 * re.findall(d + f"(?={3*s + 3*d + 3*s + d})", a)
            )
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU/BbsMgDD2Pr7AsVQoxRFuzwxaJ7TN2aHKIFNAiZSQi7DBV@fYMSNu1U40MD7/Hs5l@/Odoy5fJrWv/NY3Og9Os0wZM1vKKAcwK64@dw92xLUxvuwxrixwkPC2B7ZTBmrJ3dZyXmuJKgBcFskA77b@dhUHbzOn0vB2G4EAooOVAQXIVe8jhStYdKrlv7gnLf0IgMBiHKPM54DLv0h5xt/DU68aAr17PfgYFB3ZAREmSkaSQMtwEPDeC/RFEMRPxeiYoBbt3bA6PF4sQFLfYQgY@wVQ9QUoC2lptcVPdHOj07OxAG740jKM1jJnRQS809BbSHyv2MLne@sxkPReo3lBEpJTm6y8)

### How it works :

I created a regex that can detect double plusses and mega-double-pluses

- `s="\W"*~-a.find("\n")` stock in `s` the string `\W\W...\W` whose length is equal to the number of character of a line minus 1. (`\W` matches any non-word character including `\n`)
- `d=f"\+(?={s}\+\+\+{s}\+).."` is the pattern for double plus (+ `..` wich will be removed on the double plus check)
- `re.findall(<pattern>, a)` returns a list containing all the matches of pattern.
- `len(re.findall()+2*re.findall()+3*re.findall()` concatenate theses lists and return the length

Comment: [-1 byte](https://tio.run/##bU/BboMwDD0vXxFZqprgBI2yw4aU7TN2YBxYEzQkCihwYKr67cwJbadJs@T42c9@dsbv@Wvo8@fRr8fBOm643@/3a3saBz9z71hXnz5tzWu1GO/Spu1t3XVF53qxCPhAULXEQ7IIYQtDuXgzgGIK@H3nYXeu4wy19iB1dpGYJ2EMJ6Qg0xRkWehDFWRykrHYAGmc82Si3GKI9iLDGrnSZcwt7ijCqWWRZRVHDg0dDQRiMcuKSjI2u2meqF6yEgA0aoYayTVlij9Viv0SiMEj8XIjMBr7L2wKj3cJMgxPWKGJjzBWrxBjA26rNvtT3RTwOnZTwA3fF4bTKsaawfNWOd72PP6xYA@jb/tZNKKVCswrqICMcXL9AQ "Python 3.8 (pre-release) – Try It Online")

Comment: `"\W%r"%{a.find("\n")-1}` can be `"\W"*~-a.find("\n")`.

Comment: @Neil and Tipping Octopus, thanks for suggestions

Answer (score 5):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 71 bytes

```
ＷＳ⊞υιυＦＬυＦＬθ«Ｊκι¿⁼⁷ＬΦ⪫ＫＶＫＫΣλ3»ＦＬυＦＬθ«Ｊκι¿∧⁼3ＫＫ⬤urdl‹1⊟ＫＤ⁴✳λ6»≔Σ⪫ＫＡωθ⎚Ｉθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nZA7a8MwEMfn6FMIT2dwIaKlHTKZtIWGUgwp3YWj2CKyZOvRDKWf3T1ZzqNrbpDu@b@fVLfc1oarcTy2UgkKb7oPfuut1A3kOa2CayEUVOYrUmHSQ0BvbyyFd6Ebj0Xsuo4HjH/IYhO6/tPAIY0u5J7CyxC4cvBU0Ln1VSovLGyM1FAJcfgy@kOEjmsNeUFjBhEKug0dqDwaTQjZfYaavzdilHp3QkGhqz2lUpAFu1NZJHRYZrFs@gnuWVpRe2k0PBT0EiSwC9pjQiudk42GiH5@XtTHNce4a8CutRLcwvlj19z5iL0axyUai8eS4MXY5JMpO7tsasCIsJP9yyYFNo@dFFjy0ch4963@AA) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes input as a binary matrix of newline-terminated strings. Explanation:

```
ＷＳ⊞υιυ
```

Read in the matrix and print it to the canvas.

```
ＦＬυＦＬθ«Ｊκι
```

Loop over all of the cells.

```
¿⁼⁷ＬΦ⪫ＫＶＫＫΣλ3»
```

If this cell and all of its neighbours are `1`s or `3`s then change this cell to a `3`.

```
ＦＬυＦＬθ«Ｊκι
```

Loop over all of the cells again.

```
¿∧⁼3ＫＫ⬤urdl‹1⊟ＫＤ⁴✳λ6»
```

If this cell is a `3` and all of the cells 3 away in all four orthogonal directions are greater than `1` then change this cell to a `6`.

```
≔Σ⪫ＫＡωθ⎚Ｉθ
```

Take the sum of the grid, clear the canvas, and output the sum in decimal.

Answer (score 4):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 135 bytes

```ruby
->a{i=0;[1,186,0x101c04125ff490407010].sum{|s|a.each_cons(y=3**i).sum{|w|w.transpose.each_cons(y).count{|z|z.join.to_i(2)&s==s}}*i+=1}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tY7bboMwDIbv@xQTFxPgJko6dtKUvghDVZZBm4kGREA9kDw7o0mp0Lbb/ReO89n@7ab7OA0FG9Ca95KRt5Qu6cvTkhwpoYIkdPVYFMkrScgzoSTDutv3RhuOcy52G1EpHZ7YQxzLyJcO5oDbhitdVzqfN0VYVJ1qe3M2Z/xVSYXbaiPDVXSvGdPWxhIYtXbYMrTWfZFqXEqVa7zndW9KU2LdNrLGYsebKxQmQBBgqT7zYygiazO7WNR323TE6F0BgktAQTaHAC5MEJwc@uO9jY6CS3C2aKz43PEpB9cD1y1eP7j3gWn25gP@8@uu@S3/lQfZ8A0)

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 37 bytes

```
Zœs3Ɗ⁺€aZ$2ịP))
3*³ṡZ€ṡ€ɗÇ⁸¡
3’Ç×Ɗ€FS
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/q6ORi42Ndjxp3PWpakxilYvRwd3eApiaXsdahzQ93LowCigIpIHly@uH2R407Di3kMn7UMPNw@@HpQF1Na9yC////Hx1tqKNAZRSrozBq6qipo6aOmjpq6qipo6aOmjrSTY0FAA)

A full program taking a Boolean matrix as its argument and printing the number of pluses. This is extensible to higher degrees of plus by changing the 3 at the beginning of the last line to a higher number. For example, [here](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/q6ORi42Ndjxp3PWpakxilYvRwd3eApiaXsdahdQ93LowCigIpIHly@uH2R407Di3kMn3UMPNw@@HpQF1Na9yC/1sYHdpkWFF8aKWF0eH2/wA) is a version that goes up to mega-mega-mega double pluses in a matrix of 82x82 1s.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES2020), 136 bytes

```javascript
m=>m.map((r,y)=>r.map((c,x)=>t+=(d=X=>D=Y=>e+2?m[Y+e--%3%2]?.[X+e%2]*D(Y):e=3)(x)(y,e=3)?D(y-3)*D(y+3)*d(x-3)(y)*d(x+3)(y)?6:3:c),t=0)|t
```

```js
f=

m=>m.map((r,y)=>r.map((c,x)=>t+=(d=X=>D=Y=>e+2?m[Y+e--%3%2]?.[X+e%2]*D(Y):e=3)(x)(y,e=3)?D(y-3)*D(y+3)*d(x-3)(y)*d(x+3)(y)?6:3:c),t=0)|t


testcases = `
-+-
+-+
+--

-+-
+++
+++

++++++
++++++
++++++
++++++

----+-----
+--+++----
----++----
-+--+--++-
+++++++++-
-+--+--++-
----+-+---
---+++----
+---++++++

++++++++++
++++++++++
++++++++++
++++++++++
++++++++++
++++++++++
++++++++++
++++++++++
++++++++++
`.trim().split('\n\n').map(s => s.split('\n').map(r => [...r].map(c => c === '+' ? 1 : 0)));

testcases.forEach(t => { console.log(f(t)); });
```

```javascript
m=> // input 0-1 [m]atrix
m.map((r,y)=> // for each [y]-th [r]ow
r.map((c,x)=> // for each [x]-th [c]eil
t+= // [t]otal points add...
(d=X=> // Check if [d]ouble plus exist on [X], [Y]
D=Y=>e+2?         // for [e]ach 3, 2, 1,  0, -1
m[Y+e--%3%2]?.    //         Y+ 0, 0, 1,  0, -1
[X+e%2]           //         X+ 0, 1, 0, -1,  0
                  // check if certain position is a plus sign
*D(Y,e)           // return 0 or NaN as falsy
:e=3              // return 3 as truthy
)
(x)(y,e=3)? // Is [x][y] a double plus?
D(y-3)*D(y+3)*d(x-3)(y)*d(x+3)(y)? // Is [x][y] a double double plus?
6:3:c // assign different points
),
t=0 // initial [t]otal points to 0
)|t // return total points
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) (`-00p`), 125 bytes

```perl
/(....)?(..)?(.)
/;($a,$:,$;,$,)=map"."x$_,@-;/(1$,111$,1)(?{$x+=2})($;(1..1..1)$:1{9}$:(?3)$;(?1)(?{$x+=3}))?^/s;$_=y/1//+$x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rU7LCsIwELznM8oesmwejeLBhhK/xNKDB8FHUA8t0l835lFF8eqQnUyG3dn43eWwCqMmbbQ9jjDYoLmKQMcLIdOWQy@gEWAFCGyPva9UNUAnNtJqbkAYkwi5u8NA7WJCDpYbpdJBaMx9PUHD3RKj7d59ywnRbfXVQteOcb8mGEKQJBlJiiUZyw@iXIlm/XsxGUGJ0rSMVpbZnSXlBiqJBV9uSaB57JVARX984GPt3@Xj7G/78@kaZF0f/BM)

Using `1` instead of `+` and using regex to match pluses.

Or 124 bytes using `}{` at the end trick

```perl
/(....)?(..)?(.)
/;($a,$:,$;,$,)=map"."x$_,@-;$\=y/1//;/(1$,111$,1)(?{$\+=2})($;(1..1..1)$:1{9}$:(?3)$;(?1)(?{$\+=3}))?^/s}{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rU7LasMwELzrLxr2oGW1kpWQQyyM@gP9A9PiQwKBtDFxDjHGvx5FD7ek9NpFOzsadkbq95fTNoyGjDUO2uZl6EZojwdoXTBSx0IvC6AwTkKnoFbgFChsPrt@pVc3@FCvnMxjDDHOSAvK2gQo/QQtNesZJThptU4HobbTboZa@g1G2f/sbWZE/26GeQqBiQUxxWYh8oUod4KF/x2CY1GC5OYoZZrVhVJeoJJY6pdaEmixfSdQ4U8feHr23@n93F@P568hcFX1gd@2urIP)